# Unity 2D climbing with a sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am starting to get Unity a bit better.

My code recognizes when I am at the wall, and can make him climb but I do that by turning off gravity scale or rather setting it to 0 when on wall is true.

And then when off wall returning it to the original setting.

It doesn't seem right. I mean it goes up and then when the distance exceeds the conditional the gravity scale returns to the original setting but if I release the mobile joystick unless the gravity scale is reset again it keeps going up and even still it acts like addforce more than translate. I'm still new to Unity so I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

What I need is for if mobile joystick is all the way up using its vertical value than move up the wall if it is at 0 than pause on the wall and stay at that point and if down for him to climb down.

Here are my three functions:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "climbable") {
        is_on_wall = true;
        currentWall = col.gameObject.transform;
        currentWallCollider = col.collider;
    }
}


private bool found_wall() {

    if (currentWall) {
        if (Physics2D.Distance (currentWallCollider, heroCollider).distance < 10) {
            rb.gravityScale = 0;
            return true;
        } else {
            rb.gravityScale = 25;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void climb()  {
    if (vertical > 0.5f) {
        transform.Translate (0, 1f, 0);
    } else if (vertical < -0.5f) {
        transform.Translate (0, -1f, 0);
    } else {
        transform.Translate (0, 0, 0);
    }
}


private void FixedUpdate() {

    if (can_jump()) {
        rb.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight));
    }

    if (found_wall ()) {
        climb ();
    }
}
```

and they are called in fixed update.

Comment: "It doesn't seem right" doesn't tell us anything. Can you elaborate what isn't right?

Comment: sorry i mean it goes up and then when the distance exceeds the conditional the gravity scale returns to the original setting but if i release the mobile joystick unless the gravity scale is reset again it keeps going up and even still it acts like addforce more than translate... im still new to unity so im not sure what im looking for

Comment: What is this vertical value you check upon? is it possibly related to your joystick?

Comment: Can you include all the relevant code like `FixedUpdate` and how those variables are set/used? It's like every function uses its own set of variables and I have no idea how they are linked.

Comment: yes the verticle value is based on mobile joystick